# An open source, self-contained PHP webchat application that can require user registration?

Tags: web-apps, chat

Is there such a program that either always requires user registration or can be configured to require it?

What I need is a program I can put on a website to allow visitors to textchat with each other in a room. Since I do not want to allow any Tom, Dick or Harry to chat there whenever they want, there should be a facility where a person can apply to register an account. This could be by filling in a form with their suggested username, password, and email address. The program would then email me as admin and I could authorise the creation of their account, so that they could then login whenever they wanted, using their username and password. Or I could do the authorisation when logged in online.

The program needs to be self-contained. It should not call a program that runs on some other website that is then linked to by my page, which would make the chat dependent on the other site being up and properly functioning.

I am aware of PhpFreeChat, and I have installed it and read the documentation at phpfreechat.net. But it appears that the open source version does not allow the administrator to require user registration. It is possible that there is a way of doing it, but I have not been able to find it.

Perhaps there are other programs available?

Comment: Start with one of the Free licensed (GPL2/3/AGPL/etc) scripts out there and either modify it yourself or pay someone to modify it for you.  This is the open source business model - free software, support yourself or contract for support from someone else.  This allows competition for support services, which means they have incentive to be good....

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. There is an open source version of PhpFreeChat which would be fine, except that as it stands it doesn't have a function for requiring user registration. I'm not asking for something I have to modify or pay someone else to modify.